# Dart: Wait for template to finish

Tags: templates, dart, dart-polymer

I have a HTML with some templates in it and a function which changes the template which is bound.
The Function looks like this:

```dart
void onHover(Event e, var detail, Node sender) {
    this.querySelector('#tempToBind').setAttribute("ref", "Btn2");

    this.querySelector('#Btn2').onMouseLeave.listen((e) {
    this.querySelector('#tempToBind').setAttribute("ref", "Btn1");
}
```

Btn2 should be shown when the Mouse enters Btn1 and if the Mouse leaves Btn2, Btn1 should be shown again. If i query for Btn2 is always `null` and i guess its because the template has not finished loading.
It there a way to get a callback, when the template finished loading?

Templates look like this:

```dart
<template>
<!-- some content here -->
    <template id="tempToBind" bind ref="Btn1"></template>

<template>

<template id="Btn1">
 <div><button>1</button><div>
</template>
<template id="Btn2">
 <div><button>2</button><div>
</template>
```

Comment: Your text below the code seems to be missing something '... If I query for Btn2 is always ??? and I guess ...'

Comment: Its null. I correct it

Comment: It is also not obvious what happens when you set the attribute `ref`.  How is it implemented to show/hide buttons? Can you please add the HTML including the template tags?

Comment: Both template contain a Div, which contains a Button.

Comment: Do you use a Polymer element or an auto-binding-dart element or what kind of template are you using? I can't see anything in your HTML that would match for `"#tempToBind"`

Comment: I don't think the template element works this way but I'm not sure because I never used it outside a polymer element. If it works at all this way I think my answer still holds.

Comment: Well its is a Polymer Element and the binding like this does work. The problem is only that the second Query inside the function is null, since it hasnt loaded when its called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as  I know there is no event but normally delaying the execution by `new Future(() => ...)` or `scheduleMicrotask` should do.

```dart
void onHover(Event e, var detail, Node sender) {
  this.querySelector('#tempToBind').setAttribute("ref", "Btn2");
  scheduleMicrotask(() {
    this.querySelector('#Btn2').onMouseLeave.listen((e) {
    this.querySelector('#tempToBind').setAttribute("ref", "Btn1");
  });
}


void onHover(Event e, var detail, Node sender) {
  this.querySelector('#tempToBind').setAttribute("ref", "Btn2");
  new Future(() {
    this.querySelector('#Btn2').onMouseLeave.listen((e) {
    this.querySelector('#tempToBind').setAttribute("ref", "Btn1");
  });
}
```

Comment: tried it with scheduleMicrotask: 
`scheduleMicrotask(() => this.querySelector('#tempToBind').setAttribute("ref", "Btn2")); this.querySelector('#Btn2').onMouseLeave.listen((e) {
    this.querySelector('#tempToBind').setAttribute("ref", "Btn1");`

Its still null, but im not sure if I've done it correctly since, i havent done much with async.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about `scheduleMicrotask` but with `Future` it works like shown in my updated answer.

Comment: Future did work. with scheduleMicrotask its still `null`. How does `new Future()` actually delay the query until the template is laoded?

Comment: `new Future()` doesn't care or know about the template, the closure passed to the `Future` is enqueued in the event queue and executed when all other previously scheduled tasks are done. If you change the template, this enqueues a task and after that you enqueue another task. This is a simple and effective way to solve this problem. `scheduleMicrotask` is more finegrained and might be executed before other enqueued tasks. See more details here https://www.dartlang.org/articles/event-loop/